# Navigation of pages and running in the background

Tags: c#, uwp

In UWP (XAML / C#) I use `Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));`, and in C# of Page2 I use timer and when I use `Frame.GoBack();`, the frame really goes back, but the timer is not stopped - I mean the page and all its components are still running in the background, and the app is consuming too much RAM because of that. How can I "kill" the page?

note: if user uses this navigation 10 times, the page is 10 times in the background and it is bad..

Comment: What timer do you use?

Comment: `Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer`, but this is not problem of timer (I just find it thanks to timer and breakpoint at _timer.Tick, but the problem is that all components and all the page is still in the background).

Comment: Don't forget to stop the timer explicitly once you navigate away from the page. `DispatcherTimer` creates a strong reference between `Dispatcher` and your page when it is running.

Comment: So in `protected override void OnNavigatedFrom` I will use `_timer.Stop();`, but that's all? Other components and data entities of the page will be removed by garbage collector?

Comment: It will, if there are no other references to the page that could keep it from being GC'ed. You should also look for any direct references to your page, non-unsubscribed events from static objects, complex data bindings -- all these can cause memory leak.

Comment: @Yarik Your suggestions was very good. I think you could make it as an answer. It would be helpful other community members.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that CLR garbage collector is the one who is responsible for "killing" unused objects. An object (and all of it's members) becomes "unused" when it is no longer referenced.

When you start a `Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer`, it adds itself to a timer collection inside the current `Dispatcher`, thus, creating a direct reference between the `Dispatcher` and the timer. The timer, in its turn, holds a reference to the page where it is running. Since the `Dispatcher` is a global object, it will keep your page alive until the timer is stopped.

There can be other causes of memory leak (it is a pretty broad topic), including:

- Other sources of direct or indirect references to your page;
- Subscriptions to static events;
- Complex data bindings like `{Binding Path=Property.Subproperty}`;

I would suggest you to use a memory profiler to find memory leaks if the above doesn't help, such as the Diagnostic Tools included in Visual Studio 2015.